# How to make boolean editable as checkboxes in djano-admin change_list panel?

Tags: django, django-admin

One of my model as a boolean field (name of the field = deactivated).
This field is displayed with "green checked" or "red unchecked" icon in tha change list admin panel.
I would like to have this boolean field editable with checkboxes in the change list panel

I've read documentation and google my question but could not find solution...
the best I found is define an action that make selected row checked/unchecked...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `list_editable = ('name_of_field',)` in your class in `admin.py`